# Iphone-pushViewController is not working in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an app which has been created in Xcode 3.2.5. My app is working as expected in XCode 3.2.5 but because of some memory issues now I am using Xcode 4.2.

Xcode 4.2 offers a tool to convert existing code into  ARC [which stands for Automatic Reference Counting.] enabled code . Select **Edit -> Refactor... -> Convert to Objective-C ARC**…worked for me.

In my code I am using navigationController  to switch between views on UIbutton click.
UIButton created programmatically. I am using following code to push view controller on button_click:

```
 -(void) button_click:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"button_clicked.....");
SecondView  *sv = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sv animated:NO];
}
```

On button_click console showing message **button_clicked….**. but pushViewcontroller not pushing SecondView.

**pushViewController is working in XCode 3.2.5** but in XCode 4.2 button click is working but navigationController's pushviewController is not working.

how can i fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is there any crash in this? the code snippet is right.

Comment: App is not crashing. Nothing happens on button click only NSLog message appears in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try putting the RootViewController into a navigation controller on the MainWindow.xib?

Addition to my answer:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // create the MyView controller instance:
    MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    // set the title that appears in the navigation bar:
    [controller.navigationItem setTitle:@"Main View"];

    // create the Navigation Controller instance:
    UINavigationController *newnav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    // set the navController property:
    [self setNavController:newnav];

    // release both controllers:
    [newnav release];
    [controller release];

    // add the Navigation Controller's view to the window:
    [window addSubview:[navController view]];

    return YES;
}
```

or

```
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Handling NavigationControllers is explained in detail [here](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html)

Comment: Thanx stackr, I've created navigationController programmatically so I put [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController]; in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function of appdelegate file...Now navigationController working properly.

Comment: Explain in more detail why that can solve the problem, why you ask the question. Reformulate it into an answer, please! Mention me in a comment, so I can remove my downvote after edit.